# ethminer not recognizing multiple GPUs (AMD Radeon / Ubuntu)

Tags: gpu, ubuntu, ethminer

I have 5 GPUs on my setup currently:

```
$ sudo aticonfig --list-adapters
  * 0. 01:00.0 AMD Radeon (TM) R7 370 Series
    1. 02:00.0 AMD Radeon (TM) R7 370 Series
    2. 03:00.0 AMD Radeon (TM) R7 370 Series
    3. 04:00.0 AMD Radeon (TM) R7 370 Series
    4. 05:00.0 AMD Radeon (TM) R7 370 Series
```

However ethminer only seems to recognize one:

```
$ sudo ethminer --list-devices
[OPENCL]:
Listing OpenCL devices.
FORMAT: [deviceID] deviceName
[0] Pitcairn
    CL_DEVICE_TYPE: GPU
    CL_DEVICE_GLOBAL_MEM_SIZE: 2681208832
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_MEM_ALLOC_SIZE: 1073741824
    CL_DEVICE_MAX_WORK_GROUP_SIZE: 256
```

I followed the GPU setup instructions here: https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/wiki/Mining#gpu-mining

Any advice on getting ethminer to recognize all GPUs?

Comment: I had this once, a reboot was enough, perhaps in your case too.

Comment: @NicolasMassart I wish that was the fix. I've tried rebooting among many other things.

Comment: Have you tried to run the following command ? `sudo aticonfig --initial --adapter=all` and then reboot ?

Comment: Given your log i would say you didn't install the right drivers.

Comment: I downloaded the latest drivers from AMD for the appropriate chipset and OS. I caved in and purchased ethOS - they're mining fine now. But would be awesome to not have to purchase an OS for future rigs.

Comment: Ah, it's a shame you gave money to those people that sell free software... I guess you had a problem with the drivers. You should have tried GenEthOS which is a free ubuntu version prepared for mining : https://ethereum-mining.info/en/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally fixed my issue. Here's what I had to do:

- From the BIOS, I had to set the motherboard to use PCI-e graphics (it was set to use onboard graphics).
- I had to make sure I plugged any monitor into the GPU on the 16x PCI-e slot (I have an ASRock BTC Pro motherboard, and there is on 16x PCI-e slot, and 5 1x).

With that done all seemed to magically work.

Answer (score 4):

For people who're having this problem with a headless Windows box:

ethminer must be started from the system, not via Remote Desktop and there should be a dummy plug or a real monitor connected to one GPU.

**This is how I solved it:**

1. create a bat file which starts ethminer
2. press Windows + R -> type "shell:startup" -> ENTER
3. put a link to your .bat file in the folder that opens
4. Let your box [login automatically](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-automatically-login-in-windows-10/)
5. reboot and you're done

If you want to check on the system from time to time remotely, use Teamviewer or Chrome remote desktop

Comment: I was about to buy a dummy plug, but this worked out great. Thanks!

Just to point out - you can still use Remote Desktop as long as you set Windows to automatically login before remoting into the machine.